# How to use the shortest edge path in blender to generate a dendritic texture in a specified area，

Tags: python, texturing

[image]

How to use the shortest edge path in blender to generate a dendritic texture in a specified area，like the follow image.

Comment: this is just my opinion - but i would not assume that everybody know what a dendritic texture is...so maybe you could elaborate a bit more so that hopefully more people are interested in your question and might answer...?

Comment: Hello, and welcome! You're more likely to attract answers if you make your question self-contained, even if aspects of it are obvious to you. Perhaps, briefly describe what a dendritic texture is, and why you think _Shortest Edge Path_ might be a route to achieving it, especially if you can illustrate with some  experiments of your own.